# orbit in mathematica or python

Tags: integration, wolfram-mathematica, physics, differential-equations

I have 4 diff. equations (representing orbit equations of plants)

```
x'[t] == px[t] + y[t]
y'[t] == py[t] - x[t]
px'[t] == py[t] - dVx[t]
py'[t] == -px[t] - dVy[t]
```

which i want to solve for x[t] and y[t] for any time t. The given variables are

```
x[0]==0
y[0]==0
px[0]==0
py[0]==2.0
\[Epsilon]==0.2

-dVx[t] == x[t] - (1 - \[Epsilon])*(x[t] + \[Epsilon])/((x[t] + \[Epsilon])^2 + 
           y[t]^2)^(3/2) - \[Epsilon] (x[t] + \[Epsilon] - 
           1)/(((x[t] + \[Epsilon] - 1)^2 + y[t]^2)^(3/2))

-dVy[t] == y[t]*(1 - (1 - \[Epsilon])/((x[t] + \[Epsilon])^2 + y[t]^2)^(3/
           2) - \[Epsilon]/((x[t] + \[Epsilon] - 1)^2 + y[t]^2)^(3/2))
```

How could I get x,y for any time and make a plot in the x,y plane. I tried it with NDSolve but i failed. My code is

```
In[49]:= -dVx[t] == x[t] - (1 - \[Epsilon])*(x[t] + \[Epsilon])/((x[t] + \ 
        [Epsilon])^2 + y[t]^2)^(3/2) - \[Epsilon] (x[t] + \[Epsilon] - 
         1)/(((x[t] + \[Epsilon] - 1)^2 + y[t]^2)^(3/2))

Out[49]= -dVx[t] == -(0.16/(0.04 + y[t]^2)^(3/2)) + 
          0.16/(0.64 + y[t]^2)^(3/2)

In[50]:= -dVy[t] == 
          y[t]*(1 - (1 - \[Epsilon])/((x[t] + \[Epsilon])^2 + y[t]^2)^(3/
          2) - \[Epsilon]/((x[t] + \[Epsilon] - 1)^2 + y[t]^2)^(3/2))

Out[50]= -dVy[t] == 
         y[t] (1 - 0.8/(0.04 + y[t]^2)^(3/2) - 0.2/(0.64 + y[t]^2)^(3/2))

In[56]:= DSolve[{x'[t] == px[t] + y[t], y'[t] == py[t] - x[t], 
         px'[t] == py[t] - dVx[t], py'[t] == -px[t] - dVy[t], px[0] == 0, 
         y[0] == 0, py[0] == 2.0, x[0] == 0, \[Epsilon] == 0.2}, {x[t], 
         y[t]}, t]

During evaluation of In[56]:= DSolve::dsfun: 0 cannot be used as a function.

Out[56]= DSolve[{Derivative[1][x][t] == px[t] + y[t], 
         Derivative[1][y][t] == 2., Derivative[1][px][t] == 2. - dVx[t], 
         Derivative[1][py][t] == -dVy[t] - px[t], px[0] == 0, y[0] == 0, 
         py[0] == 2., True, True}, {0, y[t]}, t]
```

I'm new to mathematica, I'm glad for any help. I could use python if that is easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many syntax erros. Try this instead:

```
\[Epsilon] = 0.2;
dVx = -(x[
      t] - (1 - \[Epsilon])*(x[
          t] + \[Epsilon])/((x[t] + \[Epsilon])^2 + y[t]^2)^(3/
          2) - \[Epsilon] (x[t] + \[Epsilon] - 
         1)/(((x[t] + \[Epsilon] - 1)^2 + y[t]^2)^(3/2)));
dVy = -(y[
      t]*(1 - (1 - \[Epsilon])/((x[t] + \[Epsilon])^2 + y[t]^2)^(3/
           2) - \[Epsilon]/((x[t] + \[Epsilon] - 1)^2 + y[t]^2)^(3/
           2)));
NDSolve[{
  x'[t] == px[t] + y[t],
  y'[t] == py[t] - x[t],
  px'[t] == py[t] - dVx,
  py'[t] == -px[t] - dVy,
  px[0] == 0,
  y[0] == 0,
  py[0] == 2,
  x[0] == 0
  }, {x[t], y[t], px[t], py[t]}, {t, 0, 1}]
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. You defined dVx = ...  What is the difference to dVx[t_]=... in which case I get an error

Comment: You used `dVy[t]=...` in the code that you posted. This will simply assign a `DownValue` of `dVy` for the symbol `t` (provided that `t` stays unevaluated). Using `dVx[t_] = ...` does work if you use `dVx[t]` in the body of `NDSolve`. (`dVx[t_]  = ...` and `dVx[t_]  := ...` are some of sevaral ways to define functions in Mathematica).

Comment: I see. The output is a list in a list right? Is there a way to define the `x[t]` of the solution for later use, something like `a=solution[[1]]`?

Comment: Yes. Try `{xsol, ysol, pxsol, pysol} = 
  NDSolveValue[{x'[t] == px[t] + y[t], y'[t] == py[t] - x[t], 
    px'[t] == py[t] - dVx, py'[t] == -px[t] - dVy, px[0] == 0, 
    y[0] == 0, py[0] == 2, x[0] == 0}, {x, y, px, py}, {t, 0, 1}];`.

Comment: Very nice. Now when I trie to plot it like this `Animate[Plot[xsol[t],ysol[t],{t,0,1}],{t,0,1}]` it does not show a plot but `Animate` runs, do you have an idea how to fix that?

Comment: Maybe you want to do this: `plot[T_] := 
  Plot[{xsol[t], ysol[t]}, {t, 0, T}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {-1, 1}}];
Manipulate[plot[T], {T, 0.001, 1}]`?

Comment: Using this I get an empty plot. Maybe I dont get numerical values for `xsol` from the `InterploatingFunction`